# Sampling with constraint

Tags: algorithm, optimization, sampling

I have some 2 million address with there Latitude and Longitude e.g (-36.63042942, 174.49784768). I have other details like street no., street name and City.

I want to  find some 50 sample address point from each city such that they are well spread in the city. Each city will have some where around 200 to 2500 addresses.

What are some computationally efficient ways to do this?

Current Solution: I am using K means to find clusters based on Latitude Longitude in each city. No. of clusters are assigned as no. of samples I would want. Then I would find the closest point to centroids and use those as one of the sample point.

This is how the Centroid of clusters look like. The black point represents data points and the red markers as a centroid.

[image]

This is how my simple points will look like if I choose them as described above.
They will just be actual points as centroid may not represent actual points.
[image]

Comment: Sounds like [k-means clustering](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K-means_clustering) should do the trick.

Comment: @Paul Yeah tried that but looking for more precise or improved version of this. I have added what I have done.

Comment: the problem is NP-hard. So unfortunately you'll have to stick with either a good approximation or give up on the idea of anything computationally efficient (or seeing the result at all in your lifetime, considering the input-size).

Comment: @Paul Yeah that sounds correct. I am looking for good approximation :)

Comment: You are looking for a kind of balance between distance to center and number of points per cluster. In your example, there is a dozen of points South-East (which are less than 200), where do you imagine the ideal center of these points ?
Do points necessary have to be bound to the closest red point ? Because your problem may have no solution.

Comment: If you have a metric of how good a set of points are, say the distribution of distances between the points and between the selected and unselected points, you can use a randomized algorithm such as 'picking any random point with distance at least d from the selected points and add it to the selected points'. You run the randomized algorithm for like 100 times and pick the best ones based on your metric.

Comment: @Vince I am looking for points which are well distributed in given area(city).  I used clustering approach as an approximation for my requirement. Which I think is a bad approximation hence looking for better suggestions.

Comment: @KevinHe Yes that is one part of the problem i.e defining a good cost function(metric) for my problem so that an optimization approach can be taken.

Comment: In fact on distance and number, either you make a cost function  containing both, either you put a constraint on one (ex: N>200, N<2500) and optimize the other one.